# Select query with joins display count result depend on third join table value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

Here the 
[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/413fd/3)  and below tabel schema with values.
I want to select `id_emp,fname_emp,TotalProject` with a condition whose `skillsid` in `(1,2)`.
Query i tried gives *wrong output*.

```
create table employee_emp(
id_emp int identity(1,1),fname_emp varchar(20),lname_emp varchar(20))
 insert into employee_emp values('John','Cena');
 insert into employee_emp values('Michel','shawn');
 insert into employee_emp values('Jay','mac');
 insert into employee_emp values('David','jackson');

create table skills_skl(
idemp_skl int,idskill_skl int
)
insert into skills_skl values(1,1);
insert into skills_skl values(1,2);
insert into skills_skl values(1,3);
insert into skills_skl values(1,4);
insert into skills_skl values(2,2);
insert into skills_skl values(2,3);
insert into skills_skl values(3,1);
insert into skills_skl values(3,4);
insert into skills_skl values(4,2);

create table employee_ejp(
id_ejp int identity(1,1),idemp_ejp int ,idproject_ejp int)
insert into employee_ejp values(1,1);
insert into employee_ejp values(1,2);
insert into employee_ejp values(1,3);
insert into employee_ejp values(2,3);
insert into employee_ejp values(2,2);
insert into employee_ejp values(3,1);
insert into employee_ejp values(4,4);
```

Query I tried

1)

```
select a.id_emp,a.fname_emp,count(b.id_ejp) TotalP from employee_emp a
join employee_ejp b on a.id_emp=b.idemp_ejp 
group by a.id_emp,a.fname_emp
```

2)

```
select a.id_emp,a.fname_emp,count(b.id_ejp) TotalP from employee_emp a
join employee_ejp b on a.id_emp=b.idemp_ejp join skills_skl c on c.idskill_skl=a.id_emp
where c.idskill_skl in (1,2)
group by a.id_emp,a.fname_emp
```

Comment: First query will just give you an over all data without the skills in (1,2) filter...so the second query needs to be corrected it seems.

Comment: @Raj: thanks for reply, bt `where` is their in my 2nd query, and it gives wrong count no as coz of group by i thnk so

Comment: @SutharMonil: thanks for ur reply, yes 1st query works fine and further have to apply condition on that result and i am missing something their

Comment: Your issue in second query is joining with skills, where way `join skills_skl c on c.idskill_skl=a.id_emp` should say join skills_skl c on c.idemp_skl=a.id_emp`. Posted answer.

Comment: @danihp: yeah nice observe, i did wrng join for skills_skl table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the easy approach:

```
;with emps_1_2 as (
select distinct a.id_emp
  from employee_emp a
  join skills_skl c on c.idemp_skl=a.id_emp     --Be carefull here!
  where c.idskill_skl in (1,2)
)  
select emp.id_emp,
       emp.fname_emp,
       coalesce( COUNT(ejp.id_ejp), 0) as TotalProject 
from       employee_emp emp 
inner join emps_1_2 emp12 
        on emp.id_emp = emp12.id_emp
 left join employee_ejp ejp 
        on emp.id_emp=ejp.idemp_ejp
group by emp.id_emp,emp.fname_emp
```

Results:

```
| ID_EMP | FNAME_EMP | TOTALPROJECT |
-------------------------------------
|      4 |     David |            1 |
|      3 |       Jay |            1 |
|      1 |      John |            3 |
|      2 |    Michel |            2 |
```

Comment: thank your very much  for answer, can you explain lil bit more, i mean elaborate your answer so it helps to other reader

Comment: This query uses CTE. First I take pk's for emps with 1,2 skills. Then I join this table with emps to filter for this emps.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a.id_emp, COUNT(idproject_ejp) over(partition by a.id_emp) 
from #employee_emp a join #skills_skl b 
on a.id_emp = b.idemp_skl
join #employee_ejp c 
on a.id_emp = c.idemp_ejp
where b.idskill_skl in (1,2)
group by a.id_emp,idproject_ejp
```

Comment: Partitions are too heavy mate, right now wont look like that wait until you have a bigger size of data.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select emp.id_emp, emp.fname_emp, count(proj.idemp_ejp) as project_count  
from employee_emp emp  
join skills_skl sk  
on emp.id_emp=sk.idemp_skl and sk.idskill_skl in (1,2)  
join employee_ejp proj  
on proj.id_ejp=emp.id_emp  
group by emp.fname_emp, emp.id_emp
```

First making employee table as the base, then using skills as the filter on the join clause thus reducing the data size then and there.
Second, joining project table so that we can count the no. of times the employee has appeared in the table.

Short and sweet.

Comment: Had a tough time writing your column names without making spelling mistakes, bloody intellisense has ruined my grasp on remembering variable and column names :D

Comment: Thank you for doing so much effort, well i had posted sqlfidle in my question and you can direct use that for your convinience, btw thank again for ur answer

Comment: i run you query heres the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/413fd/51  it still give wrong count and danihp query wrks fine